# NPE Setting Object Value in Composed Realm Object

Tags: android, realm

I'm new to realm.
I'm trying to insert a single object in realm:
My model is:

```
public class Citizen extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("idCitizen")
    private long id;
    private String postalSection;
    private int localityId;
    private int stateId;
    private int age;
    private String gender;
    private Evaluation evaluation;
    private User user;
    @SerializedName("degree")
    private Grade grade;
    .... // getters and setters
}
```

Grade Model:

```
public class Grade extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @SerializedName("idDegreeGrade")
    private int gradeId;
    @SerializedName("gradedsc")
    private String grade;
    // ... getters and setters
}
```

This is what I do when I try to insert an object:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(ctx);
realm.beginTransaction();
Citizen citizen = realm.createObject(Citizen.class);
citizen.setAge(age); // This is OK
citizen.setGender(gender); // This is OK

Grade grade = new Grade();
grade.setGradeId(gradeId);
citizen.setGrade(grade); // This generate NPE
```

The thing is when I debug, neither citizen nor grade are null.
I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.realm.CitizenRealmProxy.setGrade(CitizenRealmProxy.java:180)
at com.myapp.action.CreateCitizenTask.onPostExecute(CreateCitizenTask.java:109)
```

It also happen when I try to set user:

```
citizen.setUser(myuser);
```

Any idea why???

Comment: We have an issue following this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1558 . And same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010688/setting-a-realmobject-to-another-realmobject-after-retrieving-it-from-realm/33029428#33029428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composed object must be created by:

```
 Grade grade = realm.createObject(Grade.class);
```

and not by:

```
 Grade grade = new Grade()
```